# C# - restart a program or end it with Console.ReadKey()

Tags: c#, if-statement, do-while

I want the user to decide if he wants to end the program or start again by pressing a key (doesn't matter which one). If I do it like this, the user has to press a key twice to end the program. I would like to know how to write it so the user only has to press once. The problem is: the program starts again if the user writes yes and I would like to keep that.

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Again? Enter \"yes\". Otherwise press any key.");
    again = Console.ReadLine();
    if (again != "yes")

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
}
while (again == "yes") ;

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: remove this line:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

The reason why you have to press the key twice is because after exiting the do/while loop your programm is hanging in that line and waiting for an input from the console. Only a second press will relase it and it can finish up.

Another point is the `Console.ReadLine();` expects the user to confirm the input using <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. So in your case the user cannot press simply any key, but has always to press also <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: That's what I thought, too. But it seems like that's not the case. I still have to double tab a key.

Comment: @Goja the thing is that the user has always to confirm the input by pressing the enter key since this is what `Console.ReadLine();` expects. So the user cannot press just any key, he has to press always also the enter key. Pressing for example twice the space key will not finish your programm

Comment: So I can forget Console.ReadKey...
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Goja do you mean is there a way where the user has to press any key only once to end the program?  there is, will be quite complicated though, because you would have to have a second loop inside that reads the user input char by char and checks for the enter key. Otherwise you have no way to distringuish whether the first input character is supposed to end the program or is it the first letter of the `ja` ;)

Comment: @Goja what you could do is to reverse the input rules for the user like this: "To Exit press only ENTER" and "To repeat press and other letter and confirm with ENTER" Then in the `while` segment you would check for emptyness of the input: `while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(again))` This will allow you to cancel with only one key press :) hope it helps